# Is there an API for Amazon compute savings plan for amazon ec2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-savings-plans

Currently the ec2 instance savings plan rate can be retrieved through boto3's `pricing` client `get_products()`. However it does not seem to offer the compute savings plan rates.

Where in the API can I retrieve the compute savings plan rates?

Edit:
The `describe_savings_plan_rates` is not suitable as I want a non truncated value

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed an API for savings plans, the functions are documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/savingsplans/index.html).

And available in the Boto3 SDK [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/savingsplans.html).

For the rates themselves you can use the [describe_savings_plan_rates](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/savingsplans.html#SavingsPlans.Client.describe_savings_plan_rates) function.

Comment: I see, however the `describe_savings_plan_rates` truncate the hourly commitment. This is why I used `pricing.get_products()` as it gives the flat usage which I can divide by the number of hours to get a more accurate hourly commitment. Is there an equivalent for the compute savings plans?

Comment: Unfortunately that is all that is provided via the APIs as far as I can tell